# How to limit or set a max number of allowed checkbox selections? - Shopify website

Tags: javascript, html, forms, shopify, liquid

Link to website: https://island-paradise-tours.myshopify.com/products/full-day-excursion-6-hours (password = **paradiseTours**)

I am working for the first time in Shopify and in hopes to find out how to limit the total number of checkboxes a user can select when they are going through the steps of selecting "What activities would you like to add?"

You will see this on the page after you select a date/time for the service. I need it to cap at 4 checkboxes max to just throw an alert. I can spice the design up later, but just need to catch an error.

Like I said, I'm using Shopify and I am using a plugin or app called Propel Appointment Booking. It allows you to add custom questions (i.e. Checkbox), but I can't set a max limit.

Overall, the goal is to make sure the user doesn't select more than 4 of the 11 checkboxes. And at the moment, I have no way of adding a specific ID or Class to the input field to call it. Little lost.

Code I am using:

```
window.onload = function () {
    const input = document.querySelector('input[type=checkbox]');
    function check() {
        if (input.checked) {
            alert("checked");
        } else {
            alert("You didn't check it.");
        }
    }
    input.onchange = check;
    check();
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just register your event listener for all checkboxes, and keep a running total of how many are checked:

```js
let totalChecked = 0;
function check(input) {
  if (input.checked) {
    // increment/decrement checked total based on state
    totalChecked++;
  } else {
    totalChecked--;
  }

  if (totalChecked === 4) {
    alert("Too many checked");
    input.checked = false; // If you want to uncheck the box that caused it to exceed the limit.
  }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]"); // Get all checkboxes
  checkboxes.forEach((cb) => {
    if (cb.checked) totalChecked++; // Count how many are checked
    cb.addEventListener("change", () => check(cb)); // Register change event listener for each one.
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you @dylan! This works outside of Shopify from what I see. I honestly am stumped here. I pulled your code down into VS code and all worked. However, implementing into my Shopify site, it doesn't work. Still troubleshooting...wondering if it's because it's a third party app for the booking service.

Comment: If it helps, I added the image of the exact code block from inspecting.